# Using all-pole filter to model the Room Impulse Response

Tags: filters, filter-design, acoustics, poles-zeros

Why is all pole model pretty useful in modelling room acoustics?

Is it related to reverberation?

Comment: Source please? Why do you think an all pole filter is useful in room acoustics?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to say that an all-pole filter is useful for *correcting* room acoustics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not because of reverberation.

When you want to model the Frequency Response of the room, it's common to simplify your approximation by using either all-pole or all-zero models. You don't want to use the full zero-pole model.

To get some intuition:

- zeros correspond to time delays and antiresonances
- poles correspond to resonances of your Room Response

In practice all-zero models are not being used due to various reasons, such as:

- required filter length is comparable to the IR length, and almost 40x the length of corresponding all-pole filter
- filter will be valid only for specific distances and positions between the source and receiver (remember: time-delays).

---

That is why the all-pole model is used instead. As mentioned above, poles correspond to the resonances, i.e. standing waves, which are:

- independent of the source location (quite intuitive)
- independent of the receiver location (except of the nodes)

Additionally the required filter length is way less than in case of all-zero models. According to Mourjopoulos, for $RT_{60}\approx0.5 \mathrm{s}$, the required order is within the range of $50 < N < 500$.  The same author, concludes that all-pole filters are easier to manipulate than all-zero filters, due to their filter length. Morevover, author mentioned that all-pole filters are sufficient approximation than using raw impulse response data.

---

Here is some literature:

> [Mourjopoulos J. - **On the Variation and Invertibility of Room Impulse
>   Response
>   Functions**](http://ee301.wdfiles.com/local--files/dsp1/sdarticle-4.pdf)
>
> [Mourjopoulos J., Paraskevas M. A. - **Pole and Zero Modelling of Room
>   Transfer
>   Functions**](http://www.wcl.ece.upatras.gr/audiogroup/publications/pdfs/pole_zero_md.pdf)